# Does it make sense to say something is as _ as something else is _ if the 2 adjectives are opposites?

Tags: adjectives, comparison, comparative-constructions

Does it make sense or not to use this form…

> A is as X as B is Y

…if X and Y are antonyms? For example "He is as tall as she is short" to say that he is very tall?

Comment: "Coal is as white as milk is black" is a way to say that coal is black.

Comment: @YellowSky What? Coal is as white? What is going on ...

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is fine. The usage in your example is a way of contrasting the heights of the two people.

Comment: I am not sure about this answer. Can you add some sources please? May be a few different examples would be great.

Comment: @AIQ, I remember reading this type of expression, but I have no idea where, and the authors I most often read would not be accepted as authorities for English usage anyway.

Comment: I remember sth like this too. And now it's kind of bugging me because I can't put a finger on it. I don't remember what this sort of comparison is called.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's indicating that the degree of difference is the same.